# List GitHub Sponsor Subscriptions for a given PAT

Tags: github-api

HI all I am trying to build a Node.js script that takes a GitHub Personal Access Token (PAT) via environment variable and fetches the sponsor subscriptions (i.e. who and what they are sponsoring) for the access token owner. I am fine with either using the GraphQL or REST API.

Is it even possible to get info of the PAT without providing a username?

Basically I am struggling to figure out how to implement the following: given a PAT get the owner information.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was looking for `viewer`. Here is a sample query:

```
viewer {
  login
  name
}
```